# How can I generate the list of `EntityField`s for a `PersistEntity`?

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I was trying to implement some form of `repsertBy`: `repsert` where the key is a provided Unique, in the line of `getBy`, `upsertBy` etc.

My approach: implement it on top of `upsertBy`.  Now `upsertBy` takes a unique constraint, a record, and a list of changes to apply in case of a unique collision.  To implement `repsertBy` I'd like that list of changes to be “assign all fields to the new value”.

```
repsertBy :: (MonadIO m, PersistRecordBackend record backend)
          => Unique record -> record
          -> ReaderT backend m (Entity record)
repsertBy unique record = upsertBy unique record [ entifyField =. value | … ]
```

And there I'm stuck.

I can generate the list of values by calling `toPersistValue` on the record's `toPersistFields`.   But where can I get the `EntityField`s from?

I'd have expected them to be available somewhere from the entity definition at `èntityDef`, but haven't found any as of now.  I've tried comparing with actual backends' implementations of replace and upsert, but only found SQL-level string banging.

I'm currently spelling out the fields by hand, but at some point I'm going to add one in the entity and forget to update it in the `repsertBy`.  Is there any way to access the `EntityField`s?